# Не получается взять MID SQL

Tags: sql

Необходимо преобразовать [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в дату, понимаю что топорный способ но идея в том, чтобы получить отдельно дату, месяц и год и потом с помощью DATEFROMPARTS, слепить из этого дату. Не могу вывести месяц ни с помощью MID ни с помощью SUBSTRING.
Ошибки которые выдает запрос указал после кода.
Может кто нибудь подскажет как сделать это другим способом.

```
SELECT LEFT(TRA_DT_ID,4) AS Y, RIGHT(TRA_DT_ID,2) AS D, MID (TRA_DT_ID,5,2) AS M
FROM sto609.dbo.yd_b2b_card
WHERE STO_NO = 643 AND TRA_DT_ID = 20211021
#Выдает ошибку: mid is not a recognized function name


SELECT LEFT(TRA_DT_ID,4) AS Y, RIGHT(TRA_DT_ID,2) AS D, SUBSTRING(TRA_DT_ID,5,2) AS M
FROM sto609.dbo.yd_b2b_card
WHERE STO_NO = 643 AND TRA_DT_ID = 20211021
#Выдает ошибку: argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of substring function
```

Comment: Судя по скрину, тип данных исходного значения числовой. А ни разу не строковый.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.